# Bioacoustics STEM Education Survey

Tags: bird, measurement, education, resources

I am a masters student in CWU's Primate Behavior & Ecology program. I am interested in Bioacoustics and STEM education. I've noticed there can be quite a learning curve for undergraduates who are interested in joining the field. Unfortunately, there's not a lot of materials that are concise, really available, and easily accessible. My goal is to create such a resource. To do this, I have designed two surveys; one survey is to assess the educational backgrounds of students (graduate and undergraduate) and their expectations regarding the field. The second survey is similar but is targeted towards established bioacoustics researchers. Using the results of these surveys, I hope to create the materials we so desperately need.

Would y'all be willing to participate or forward the links to researchers and/or students who would be?

The first link (https://cwu.co1.qualtrics.com/jfe/form/SV_doipAjq6WLEP66O) is for the professional survey.

The second link (https://cwu.co1.qualtrics.com/jfe/form/SV_08JXJxtrD7DpeVU) is for the student survey.

Neither should take more than 15 minutes.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is a survey request and not a bioacoustic question